# Best way in r to import data with rows of different lengths (daily data)?

Tags: r, import

I have daily data in excel that is stored as

```
Month Day 1, Day 2, ... Day 28, Day 29, Day 30, Day 31
1     x1     x2     ... x28,    x29   , x30   , x31 
2     y1     y2     ... y28,    
3     z1     z2     ... z28,    z29   , z30
```

etc

I have rows of different length with gaps, because there isn't a 30th Feb or 31st April

I want to be able to calculate monthly means, totals, etc. What is the best way to import this data into R? If I simply import it, I end up with NA at the end of months

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `mean(data, na.rm = TRUE)` will do the trick.

Comment: You can leave them as NAs and use `apply(dat,1,function(x){mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)}`

Comment: There is an option `na.rm` which would be suitable for your case

Comment: Thanks a lot, one further complication - I have weather data, and some data is genuinely missing (the weather station didn't work that day), and in other cases the data couldn't have possibly existed (rainfall on 31st February). Is it possible to differentiate between the two?

Comment: Would it just be the difference between an NA in a middle column versus one of the end columns?  Also - I know there are packages (like lubridate) that incorporate things like how many days each month has that may help identify missing vs impossible data

Answer (score 0):

You can just import the data set normally and deal with the `NA`s when you process the data. A lot of basic functions have the `na.rm = TRUE` option.

Otherwise you could get rid of the `NA`s and save each month as a `vector` in a `list` and then you use `lapply` to calculate the measures (e.g. `mean`) you want for each `vector` in the `list`.